# Wait for listener completion

Tags: java, concurrency

I will be talking purely conceptual here.

I have a class which has a listener attached to it which does ***something***.
I have a whole array of the objects that are constructed from that class

I also have a static method `foo()` which access that array and then does ***something else***.

Doing ***something else*** triggers the listener and if I don't pause ***something else*** until ***something*** is done, code doesn't work. `foo()` knows when the listener is triggered.

Also, listener has a capability to directily invoke a listener on another object that was constructed out of the same class. `foo()` can't know if this will happen or not, or how many times.

So how can I force `foo()` to wait for listener to execute, and then, if the listener hasn't triggered a chain reaction, continue where it left off, or otherwise wait for any triggered listener to finish executing?

Comment: `wait for any triggered listener to finish executing` - this implies that triggered listener is executed not as a method invocation, but in some parallel way - as a thread, a Runnable/Callable on a thread pool, or some other way. But you did not describe the nature of the listeners. How we can say how to wait if we don't know what to wait?

Answer (score 2):

Since this is conceptual and it's hard to nail down an exact answer, I'd recommend reading about `Locks` and `Conditions` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html. These may provide the capabiliites you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider using additional listeners:

- `foo()` could add a PropertyChangeListener to whatever your "listener" is changing the state of, let's call it the model.
- then have the model, notify foo when it has completed its task by firing a notification method on the PropertyChangeSupport that its state has changed..
- Then foo could remove its listener after it has completed its action..